# amp-experiment info not visible in GA or Google Optimize

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

I've implemented a small experiment on an AMP site following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/amp-experiments

Here's what I've done:

**1. amp-analytics and amp-experiment components**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-experiment" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-experiment-0.1.js"></script>
```

**2. Code for the experiment**

```
<amp-experiment>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "AMP_Product_Page": {
        "sticky": true,
        "variants": {
          "Original": 50,
          "Variant_1": 50
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-experiment>
```

**3. Code for analytics**

```
<amp-analytics id='analytics1' type='googleanalytics'>
    <script type='application/json'>
    {
        "vars": {
        "account": "UA-105350-7"
        },
        "requests": {
        "experiment": "${pageview}&xid=${xid}&xvar=${xvar}"
        },
        "triggers": {
            "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "experiment",
            "vars": {
                "xid": "fB2hAs9HS2WgWqe332c6Ow",
                "xvar": "VARIANT(AMP_Product_Page)"
            }
        }
        }
    }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

**4. Created an experiment in Google Optimize**

I created an experiment in Google Optimize and used the ID in the code above. I can also see the experiment in Google Analytics, it has 0 sessions, though.

---

I've also added some basic CSS rules and they are working fine.

The code above is live and I can see the experiment running on the site, also the `<body>` tag has an attribute `amp-x-amp_product_page="Variant_1"`.

---

**Google Analytics requests**

I have a Google Analytics integration deployed using GTM AMP container and it's working fine.

Now, when I look at the requests made by Google Analytics, here's what I see:

1. Pageview request (OK)
2. Second pageview request with experiment data (status 302)

[image]

[image]

[image]

That second request seems not to make it to GA.

[image]

[image]

---

I tried sending experiment data with an event, but it seems like `xid` and `xvar` are not allowed variables for an event in amp-analytics.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Not yet @chris. Still doing some heavy debugging and testing of possible solutions. Will post here if I find something. Oh, and please do the same if you manage to find the solution.

Comment: I just got it working by moving the experiment and analytics code blocks (your 2 and 3) from head to body. I hope this helps!

Comment: In my case, they've been in the body all the time. I'm currently using events to send data to GA, although this way I can't use the content experiments and Google Optimize features.

Comment: Somewhere I read the variants should be numbered instead of named in <amp-experiment>. So in your case they should be "0" and "1" instead of "Original" and "Variant_1". Worth a try...

Comment: Whoa, that seems to be it! Will do some more testing but I can already see active users in Google Optimize. You might want to submit it as an answer so I could accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Great! It's always good when the tons of irrelevant (to me) info I had to read can at least help somebody else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variants should be numbered instead of named in . So in your case they should be "0" and "1" instead of "Original" and "Variant_1".